# Server not receiving client's mouse movement data

Tags: node.js, socket.io

While working on my project I cannot get my server to log out my mouse movements to let me know it is listening.

On the client side I can see the mouse movements log to the console, but for some reason the server is not receiving any mouse movements at all.

Can anyone explain to me why this is not working? I am new to node.js and this is my first project.

Server Code:

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();
var server = app.listen(3000);

app.use(express.static('public'));

var socket = require('socket.io');

var io = socket(server);

io.sockets.on('connection', newConnection);

function newConnection(socket) {
console.log('new connection: ' + socket.id);

socket.on('mouse', mouseMsg);

function mouseMsg(data) {
    console.log(data);
}



}
```

Client Code:

```
var socket;

function setup() {
createCanvas(200,200);
background(51);

socket = io.connect("http://localhost:3000/sketch.html");

}


function mouseDragged() {
console.log('Sending: ' + mouseX + ' , ' + mouseY);

var data = {
    x: mouseX,
    y: mouseY
}
socket.emit('mouse', data);

noStroke();
fill(255);
ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 15, 15);
}
```

Comment: Is it reaching to: `console.log('new connection: ' + socket.id);` ? Do you have any errors on your browser developers console? Add an error listener on your client side, and let us know if there is any error: `socket.on('error', err => console.log(err))`

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande i didn't have any errors in my developers console before inserting the snippet of code you left, I also did not have one after either. Running the same as before, do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is: `/sketch.html`, if you remove it, it will work:

```
socket = io.connect("http://localhost:3000");
```

`/sketch.html` is a namespace, so when connecting to: `http://localhost:3000/sketch.html` you should listen to events on that specific namespace.

```
const nsp = io.of('/sketch.html');
nsp.on('connection', socket => {
    console.log('connected to namespace');
    socket.on('mouse', data => console.log(data));
});
```

You can read more about `socket.io` namespaces in [here](https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/):

Comment: This worked perfect, thanks! Is there a reason why I had to remove it from there but if i want to connect to the server through my browser I have use "http://localhost:3000/sketch.html"?

Comment: Glad it worked! hmm I'm not sure I understood what you're asking, can you be a little more specific?

Comment: yeah, so in order to actually see the sketch and to be able to draw on it while having it log the mouse movements, i need to connect to localhost:3000/sketch.html - If i connect to localhost:3000 i actually get a "Cannot GET /" error instead. Seems magical that by removing the "sketch.html" path from "socket = io.connect("http://localhost:3000/sketch.html");" it fixed the issue i was having

Comment: Oh I see, but `/sketch.html` is an express route, it has nothing to do with `socket.io`, your `socket.io` server is running on port 3000, so you only need to connect to `localhost:3000`, in your specific case, you can even do: `socket = io.connect()`

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up! One step closer to getting out of noob status. You're the man Marcos.